# Google Apps Script Panel Removal

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to use a web page to gather data in stages. When the user clicks next I want to have the current panel removed from the app and a new panel added and I am having trouble making it work.

Here is my current code:

```
function doGet() {
//Create Application
var app = UiApp.createApplication();
//Set Application Title
app.setTitle("New Lead Form");

/////////////////////////////////Step 1///////////////////////////////////            

// Create a Panel for Step 1 Data


var nextbuttonstep1 = app.createButton("Next");

// Create the entry form, a 6 x 2 grid with text boxes for First Name, Last Name, Phone     Number, Email, & Property State that is then added to a vertical panel
var grid = app.createGrid(5, 2);
var propertystate = app.createListBox().setName('propertystate').setId('propertystate') 
                  propertystate.addItem('AL');
                  propertystate.addItem('FL');
                  propertystate.addItem('IN');
                  propertystate.addItem('KY');

grid.setWidget(0, 0, app.createLabel('First Name:'));
grid.setWidget(0, 1, app.createTextBox().setName('firstname').setId('firstname'));
grid.setWidget(1, 0, app.createLabel('Last Name:'));
grid.setWidget(1, 1, app.createTextBox().setName('lastname').setId('lastname'));
grid.setWidget(2, 0, app.createLabel('Phone Number:'));
grid.setWidget(2, 1, app.createTextBox().setName('phonenumber').setId('phonenumber'));
grid.setWidget(3, 0, app.createLabel('Email Address:'));
grid.setWidget(3, 1,    app.createTextBox().setName('emailaddress').setId('emailaddress'));
grid.setWidget(4, 0, app.createLabel('Property State:'));
grid.setWidget(4, 1, propertystate);

// Create a vertical panel and add the grid to the panel
var step1panel = app.createFlowPanel();
step1panel.add(grid);
step1panel.add(nextbuttonstep1);
app.add(step1panel)
var handler = app.createServerHandler('proceedtostep2');
handler.addCallbackElement(step1panel)
nextbuttonstep1.addClickHandler(handler);


return app;
}

function proceedtostep2(eventInfo) {

var parameter = eventInfo.parameter;
var panel =parameter.step1panel; 
var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();

app.remove(panel);

return app;
}
```

Comment: where / how are you getting the data to show ? why not simply update each textBox while leaving the grid in place ?

Answer (score 3):

Panels don't show up as parameters, only input fields do. You will have to retrieve the panel you want to remove using it's ID:

```
...
// Create a vertical panel and add the grid to the panel
var step1panel = app.createFlowPanel().setId('someUniqueIdString');
...
```

and

```
...
function proceedtostep2(eventInfo) {
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  app.remove(app.getElementById('someUniqueIdString'));
  return app;
}
```

But removing all elements from a application window does not close the window. The Window only remains in a ugly state.
Adding other widgets after the remove is OK but you should use some fresh ID's. If you use  old ID strings with new widgets bad things happen.

Comment: Please use the "accept answer" function if the answer solved your problem. It's the green checkmark in front of the answer.